# Is Āpastamba giving non-initiates the right to recite certain parts of the Véda in the below given sū́tra-s?

Tags: vedas, kalpa, sutra

In Praśna I, Paṭala 1, Khaṇḍa 2 of the  Āpastamba-dharma-sūtrá Āpastamba states, one who has not been initiated before the required time (1.1.28-36), should recite the seven Pāvamānīs (Şākala-saṁhitā́ 9.57.21-9.57.27) along with the Yajuṣpavitra (Tāittirīya-saṁhitā́ 1.2.1.1), Sāmapavitra (Kāuthuma-saṁhitā́ I, 2, 2, 3, 5), and the Āṅgirasapavitra (Şākala-saṁhitā́ 4.40.5), daily during their bath.

The Vyāhṛtis may also be recited. This should continue for as many years as there are uninitiated members in their family. If they are the only one, then one year is enough according to Āpastamba.

> 1. For as many years as there are uninitiated persons, reckoning (one year) for each ancestor (and the person to be initiated himself),
> 2. (They should bathe daily reciting) the seven[1] Pāvamānīs, beginning with 'If near or far,' the Yajuṣpavitra, ('May the waters,
>    the mothers purify us,' &c.) the Sāmapavitra, ('With what help
>    assists,' &c.), and the Āṅgirasapavitra ('A swan, dwelling in
>    purity'),
> 3. Or also reciting the Vyāhṛtis (bhūḥ, bhuvaḥ, svaḥ).
> 4. After that (such a person) may be taught (the Veda).

So, is Āpastamba giving non-initiates the right to recite certain parts of the Véda in the below given sū́tra-s?

Comment: Check the previous Khanda 1. It says that a person whose forefathers have not been initiated, can perform prayaschitta and then get initiated. After initiation the pavamanis etc should be recited.

Comment: Thanks, so according to my understanding the process goes as such 

2 months of brahmacarya --> upa-nayana --> 1 year of the pāvamānīs, yajuṣpavitra, sāmapavitra, and aṅgirasapavitra (assuming all previous ancestors were initiated) --> veda-ārambha

Comment: I'm taking one season to be 2 months from Olivelle.

Comment: Yes sounds about correct

Comment: @Adiyarkku Nevermind, this is just the case for the "Brahman-Killers" of sūtra 32. For one whose ancestors have been initiated, they can just follow: 2 months of the brahmacarya vidhi --> upa-nayana --> 1 year of daily bathing --> veda-ārambha.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, according to the Āpastamba-dharma-sūtra, non-initiates are allowed to recite certain parts of the Veda as a purification ritual. Specifically, they are instructed to recite the seven Pāvamānīs, the Yajuṣpavitra, Sāmapavitra, and the Āṅgirasapavitra during their daily bath for as many years as there are uninitiated members in their family. This is considered a form of preparation for initiation into Vedic study, and after completing this ritual for the specified number of years, the person may be eligible to be taught the Veda.

Comment: As mentioned in the comments, the student does get initiated first, then this process begins, also this is for the Brahman-Slayers only.